# apsr.bst - Volume in bold but without number

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I try to change a bst-file (American Political Science Review).
At the moment the output looks like:

> Rose, Gideon. 1998. “Neoclassical Realism and Theories of Foreign Policy.” *World Politics* 51(1):144–172.

but I need it like this:

> Rose, Gideon. 1998. “Neoclassical Realism and Theories of Foreign Policy.” *World Politics* **51**:144–172.

So without the number, but the volume bold.

The function in the bst file should be the following I think:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
    { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

How do I change that in order to get the second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modified version of the function should produce the desired result.

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume embolden field.or.null
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ format.pages }
    { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

For running the following example, copy `apsr.bst` to `apsr2.bst` and replace `format.vol.num.pages` as shown above.

[image: Output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Rose1998,
  author = {Gideon Rose},
  title = {Neoclassical Realism and Theories of Foreign Policy},
  journal = {World Politics},
  year = {1998},
  volume = {51},
  number = {1},
  pages = {144--172},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apsr2}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```